# html string into css - how to?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am using the Plax jQuery plugin, which uses the html-string: `data-xrange="" data-yrange=""`

Here's a fiddle of my project: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/

I would like it to be responsive, which I've almost did.
The only problem now, is when the window is minimized, the `data-xrange="" data-yrange=""`-string makes the elements move to much, because of the window size.

I am not that great at jQuery so here's my question(s):
Is it possible to adjust the `data-xrange="" data-yrange=""` either by css or jQuery?
And how would this be done?

Comment: "html string" or html attributes? You can change attributes with $(selector).attr() [thats jquery]

Answer (score 1):

If your element has an ID (or class - it doesn't matter), get it with jquery and change the attribute:

```
$('#your-element')
    .attr('data-xrange', 'New Value')
    .attr('data-yrange', 'New Value');

// You can dynamically redefine the range of a layer
// by running plaxify() on it again.
$('#your-element').plaxify();
```

Comment: doubt that simply changing attributes will update the values stored in plugin when it is initialized.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso   `prop()` is not correct as `data-` are attributes not properties but you can use `data()`

Comment: So I should use jQuery for this?

Comment: As the [Plax documentation](https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax), `You can dynamically redefine the range of a layer by running plaxify() on it again.`. So do this when changing the attributes. I updated the code...

Comment: Okay, cool. Can you show an example in the fiddle?
As mentioned I am a noob at jQuery;)

Comment: @Mojtaba – it would help me alot if you could add the code to my fiddle above, because i'm not sure what to add where?

As far as I can see your code controls all of the images OR you have to add the code to each of the images, is that correct, which would make it rather long?

And also, doesn't the code need to know at what browsersize/windowsize, the new attributes need to take effect?

Comment: @DWTBC `The only problem now, is when the window is minimized...`, in jsFiddle, it worked correctly for me, I try to resize/move the window a lot. But I couldn't find any problem. Can you give me 2 screenshot, one for the correct view and second for the problem view. So I can help you. Perhaps it's better to email me (`mojtaba` at `gmail` dot `com`).

Comment: @Mojtaba I couldn't get it to work. But can you post the link to your fiddle?

Just so I can se what you've done